# Merge/remove misspelled tag "spredsheet"

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request

This is my first time suggesting a tag merge, so I hope I'm doing this correctly.  I noticed that the tag [spredsheet](/questions/tagged/spredsheet) was misspelled on SO, and I can only assume that this is supposed to actually be "spreadsheet". Could this tag be merged/removed?

Comment: There aren't any questions using [tag:spredsheet].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you meant the [speadsheet](/questions/tagged/speadsheet) tag. I retagged the very few questions that had the tag and flagged the one that is locked so a moderator can remove the tag from that question. The tag will be killed off in short order.